# Why did my IAM policy not attach to my IAM role using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies

Part of our Terraform deployment is supposed to create a policy and a role, and then attach the one to the other.

Our current tf is:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "module_role" {
  name = var.lambda_role
  assume_role_policy = var.lambda_trust
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "sample_policy" {
  name = var.lambda_role
  description = var.lambda_policy_description
  policy = var.lambda_policy
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.module_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.sample_policy.arn
}
```

Obviously the vars are being passed in from another file.  And the whole module is called from a parent.

When our pipeline runs, it creates the policy and the role, and completes without errors.  However when I inspect the policy via the aws console, I discover that the role and policy are not attached.  Can anyone see why?

I did note [from the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment) that this resource (`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`) is meant for attaching "a *Managed* IAM Policy to an IAM role".  Our policy is not a managed one.  But I cannot find another resource in the terraform registry for aws resources that is meant for customer-managed policies.

Thanks much

Comment: Your policy is managed one, so this is not a problem. However, your code depends on lots of variables and content which is simply not shown. So its difficult to speculate on what's wrong with it.

Comment: The code looks correct, are you absolutely sure you are looking at the correct role?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, iam_policies take a string or json value in the `policy` field. maybe you could try something like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "sample_policy" {
  name = "${var.lambda_role}_policy"
  description = var.lambda_policy_description
  policy = var.lambda_policy.json
}
```

Comment: If the policy was invalid there would be errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is an old post but I just ran slap bang into the same problem so hopefully this will help someone

There does seem to be something really odd with the way Terraform handles policies and attachments. In tests I even deleted the policy and terraform did not notice and re-create on next apply.

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code from @208-man according to the documentation and it should work (in my opinion), but when trying to attach custom policies to roles with similar code I found Terraform was inconsistent. If I kept the code the same on one apply TF would generate the role and attach the policy just fine, but after making no changes and running apply again it would un-attach the policy and subsequent reruns would sometimes attach, sometimes not (again with no changes to the module). I was using the same module to create two roles with policies and found that they even ended up out of sync (one role would attach its policy and the other would not - then the other way around on subsequent re-applies).

In the end I got around the issue by attaching the policy as a managed_policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role" {
  description         = var.role_description
  name                = var.role_name
  managed_policy_arns = concat( var.managed_policy_arns, [aws_iam_policy.policy.arn])
  assume_role_policy  = var.assume_role_policy
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "${var.role_name}-policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for the role ds-${var.role_name}"
  policy      = var.role_policy
}
```

In my case I already had a list of AWS managed policies I wanted to add in *var.managed_policy_arns* so I added my own policy to this list using a concat, but if only the new policy is required the following works:

```
managed_policy_arns = [aws_iam_policy.policy.arn]
```

I honestly prefer this approach - less code, easier to see what is happening and no 'hidden' attachment objects that aren't visible in AWS. The previous behavior feels like a bug and if I can get my head around documenting it in a more sensible way I may submit it, but like I say hopefully this helps someone.